# I need an Integer representation for the Firebase push id

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, uniqueidentifier

Maybe this does not make sense but I need an Integer representation for the [Firebase push id](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) in the same way as an [Hash]

I would like if it´s possible to create an Java Integer from the Firebase [push ID](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html) in the same way as a [Hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function#Hash_function_algorithms) is created. 
This is a little experimental but wanted to see if it can be done.

Lets say I have the Firebase push id `-Kh7JD01FqBpzfCt_dVX` and I run it trough a hashing function I would each time I do that get the same hash string right.

But what if I could run the `-Kh7JD01FqBpzfCt_dVX` through some "Integer" function and I would each time I do that get the same Integer right

Yea I know I can create random Integers within the [2,147,483,647](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647_(number)) range and hope for non collisions. But I feel that this is less safe then using above method

Comment: Why don't you just convert each character from the hash to octal? Depending on the hash length you could end up with a large numeric string, but you could (by other means) convert it to an integer in the range (0, MAX_INT)

Answer (score 0):

[Firebase push IDs can hold 2^120 unique values](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/02/the-2120-ways-to-ensure-unique_68.html). That is a range that cannot be captured in an integer.

Using the `hashCode()` of a string is guaranteed to give you the same number (a `long)` every time. But that hash code is not guaranteed to be unique for the given input string: there are multiple strings that will give the same hash code.

Comment: Thanks for the info, wait a minute, the Firebase [`runTransaction()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write) can let the client lock on to a key value and get a unique Integer by increment it by one, and then use it right. Next client would not get the the same Integer because he first also increment. That feel like a Unique-Integer-generator-factory??. Now maybe I can store that Integer with the Push Id it represent right. So now I have created integers that represent Push ids??
but I could only create 2,147,483,647 of them. What do you think?

Comment: You seem to have some idea of how to implement this logic, so: go for it. If you get stuck, share the [minimal code that reproduces where you're stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).